# Show and Hide wishlist from the menu

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to hide "wishlist" from the menu if the wishlist is empty. On the web I found following css code to hide the product counter

```
.wishlist_products_counter_number:empty {
    display:none;
}
```

using the information

```
(wishlist_products_counter_number:empty)
```

I am trying to get

```
.nav-menu-primary li.menu-item-142 {display: none ;}
```

In other words if the products_counter_number is zero, display of menu-item-142 should be set to zero. Please help.

Tried:

```
.wishlist_products_counter_number:empty .nav-menu-primary li.menu-item-142) {
    display:none;
}
```

I was expecting if the product counter is zero/empty menu-item-142 will hide. Didn't work.

I am learning wordpress+woocommerse+TI WooCommerce Wishlist. I tried on the related forum but couldn't get the answer. I also tried adding to theme functions.php the following php codes (modified from internet):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpmudev_emptywishliststyles' );
function wpmudev_emptywishliststyles() {
    $wishlist = isset( $_SESSION['wishlist'] ) ? $_SESSION['wishlist'] : array();
    if (sizeof( $wishlist ) == 0 ) {
?>
<style>
.nav-menu-primary li.menu-item-142 {display: none ;}
</style>
<?php
     }
   }
```

also

```
function onze_wishlist_has_items( $haswishitems ) {
    if ( TInvWL_Public_WishlistCounter::counter() == 0 ) {

?>

<style>
.nav-menu-primary li.menu-item-142 {display: none;}
</style>


<?php
     }
   }
```

but nothing worked for me. I am very new to coding, please help.